# Inserting SVG image inside Word reduces its quality

Tags: microsoft-word

It's really bizarre. When I insert an SVG image in my thesis in Word and export it to PDF the quality is much worse than if I create a new Word document insert it and export to PDF.

The image is exactly the same.
The size is exactly the same.

I tried `Do not compress` option for image quality and when exporting I chose `Optimize For Image` quality, yet none of those things fixed it.

As far as I know these are all the options for altering the quality of an image in Word.

The Word version I am using is `Word 2019`. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least in Word 2007, there was a Registry setting that might affect quality: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office/office-docuemnt-image-quality-loss You can also set a custom page size for Print to PDF, https://franklinheath.co.uk/2015/08/29/custom-page-sizes-for-microsoft-print-to-pdf/ . Larger would have higher quality images.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That can't possibly be the solution because with same Registry settings on the same system with the same picture I get 2 different results.

Comment: As far as I know, when Word try to save a document containing a SVG vector graphic as PDF, the graphic will be converted to a raster image. It's the reason why loss of SVG image quality occurs after saving as PDF. You may need other PDF Creators, e.g.  Adobe Acrobat with Adobe Acrobat PDFMaker Office COM Addin. Reference:[MS Word: Preserving vector graphics (SVG) when saving document as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054870/ms-word-preserving-vector-graphics-svg-when-saving-document-as-pdf)

Comment: Are both images inline or both floating? If you make a copy of your thesis and remove everything except the image, then export, what happens? (I don’t have a hypothesis about what is wrong except maybe it has something to do with the size of the document or something else in the document?

Comment: What do you mean with "the quality is much worse"? What is in the SVG you are trying to insert?